# How to get the the account holder details from Indian UID (Aadhaar) Number in Android?

Tags: android, uid

I am trying to build an `Android` app, which will access [Indian UID api](https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/web/uidai/developer) from android.

The [api portal](https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/web/uidai/developer) has sample for java and c.

Looking for a sample/example project to start development in Android accessing [Indian UID api](https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/web/uidai/developer).

Comment: https://github.com/Zephrys/Auter, refer this one and https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-made-an-android-application-using-Aadhar-Api-provided-by-Indian-Govt

Answer (score 1):

yes.its possible .Aadhaar authentication service is exposed as stateless service over HTTPS. Usage of open data format in XML and widely used protocol such as HTTP allows easy adoption and deployment of Aadhaar authentication.

Sample Java application (both binary and source code zip files) to test Aadhaar authentication can be [Authentication Sample Client (Java).](https://developer.uidai.gov.in/downloads)

then 
 [Setting up Development Environment Aadhaar Authentication Basics](https://developer.uidai.gov.in/book/export/html/18)

Answer (score 0):

http://bridge.aadhaarconnect.com/ you will get info about adhar api connection or data fetch from above link.